# Custom field in MS Project 2010

Tags: microsoft-project

I want to show above task bar its start and finish date. I found that I need to create a custom field. There is a nice tutorial: http://www.mpug.com/articles/5-tips-for-formatting-text-on-a-gantt-chart/ Unfortunatelly when I enter any formula and select my custom field in task bar text it does not display anything. If I select predefined fields the text is shown.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are different bar styles for Tasks and summary tasks.  Did you set the text field for Tasks, Critical, and Summary?